# I have PyQt4 GUI where I want to list the files in form of checkboxes .But the checkboxes only display the last file in the directory

Tags: python, pyqt4

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
import os 
ch = []
class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, rows, columns):

        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(rows, columns, self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        for row in range(rows):
            qwidget = QtGui.QWidget()
            checkbox = QtGui.QCheckBox()
            checkbox.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            qhboxlayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(qwidget)
            qhboxlayout.addWidget(checkbox)
            qhboxlayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            qhboxlayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            self.table.setCellWidget(row, 0, qwidget)
            for filename in os.listdir("C:\\Python27\\Codes\\"):
                files = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
                ch.append(files)              
                self.table.setItem(row, 1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(files)))
                layout.addWidget(self.table)

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.button.setObjectName("loadButton")
        #layout.addWidget(self.table)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.ButtonClicked)

    def ButtonClicked(self):
        checked_list = []
        for i in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            if self.table.cellWidget(i, 0).findChild(type(QtGui.QCheckBox())).isChecked():
                checked_list.append(self.table.item(i, 1).text())
        print checked_list


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window(50, 2)
    window.resize(350, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I am new to pyQt4

Comment: The code only puts last file in the directory . I want all of them listed

Comment: please read [ask], review the [tour] and improve your question.

Comment: Your IF condition restricts the changes only to one, selected item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = 0
for filename in os.listdir("C:\\Python27\\Codes\\"):
    files = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    self.table.setItem(n, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(files)))
    n = n+1
```

NOTE: you dont need this loop: for row in range(rows):